# Trouble installing MySQL in Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard

I am having some problem installing MySQL in snow leopard.

I also have these tutorials but I don't know which one is easier and fast to install.

- [Apache, PHP, and MySQL in Leopard](http://whimsical.nu/2008/03/02/apache-php-and-mysql-in-leopard/)
- [Installing MySQL on Snow Leopard](http://devlog.agektmr.com/en/archives/673)

Also, if I'm going to download the MySQL installer itself, what do I need to download from here? http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#macosx-dmg

Comment: ok im sorry :) i will change it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get MySQL installed, unless this has been fixed, you will need to create a 'mysql' symlink in '/usr/local' that points to the directory 'mysql-5.0.83-osx10.5-x86', also in '/local/usr' before MySQL will start.

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success with [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), if you don't mind waiting a few minutes for it to compile.

Once you install MacPorts, run the following to install MySQL 5.1:

```
sudo port install mysql5-devel mysql5-server-devel
```

Or, for 5.0:

```
sudo port install mysql5 mysql5-server
```

Answer (score 0):

This step-by-step will give you a good install plus integrate MySQL into launchd:
[mysql on snow leopard at hivelogic.com](http://articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard/)